# Why is my virtualenv not working on terminal but working on PyCharm?

Tags: python, python-venv

I started creating the virtual environment through PyCharm and then installing the modules using pip, everything ok.
But, when i run the same venv created by PyCharm, and then try to run the Python through the terminal or vscode, i can see that the Python version in it has no one of the modules i've previously installed.

The biggest question is:
If the Python path is the same in both of the cases (PyCharm and VSCode), why can't i run the files on VSCode?

Comment: Show us the output of `get-command python` in the terminal window.

Comment: How do you "run" the venv outside of pycharm?

Comment: "i can see that the Python version in it has no one of the modules i've previously installed." how do you see that?

Comment: Did you activate venv in the terminal or vscode?

Comment: @mkrieger1 On pycharm, i run simply clicking the Run button. This is the Run configuration: https://imgur.com/a/zS0gunW

On terminal i tried:
- venv/Scripts/activate.ps1
- python C:\###l\regression\features\runner.py 

What i get is: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runner.py", line 4, in <module>
    from mongo import ENDPOINTS
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mongo'

Comment: Maybe there is no module named "mongo" in the venv, that would explain the error.

Comment: @mkrieger1 "mongo" is a package created inside the project, based on pymongo (that exists in the venv): https://imgur.com/a/oBnzOc1

But why would the error happens on vscode/terminal and not on PyCharm

Comment: Maybe you activated two different venvs. And from the screenshot it seems that the mongo package is outside the venv. So maybe it works in pycharm for a reason that is unrelated to the venv.

Comment: From the terminal, after you've activated the venv, what is the output of:
`python -c "import sys;print(f'{sys.prefix=}\n{sys.base_prefix=}\n{sys.path=}')"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate your environment first. Pycharm does this automatically in the background, so it will work in Pycharm, but not outside.

[This link](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do) explains the concept ("sourcing") in Unix (Linux, BSD, and Mac), but similar applies to Windows.

In your virtual environment folder (let's say `venv`), you will find shell specific activation files. The one for Bash (default on Linux, BSD and Mac) is found under `venv/bin/activate`, the one for Powershell (often used on Windows) can be found under `venv/bin/Activate.ps1`.

On a Unix system, you would activate your environment with `source venv/bin/activate`. Make sure you're in the right directory. On Powershell you just run the script.